# integrate commerce server with a Continuous integration server

Tags: continuous-integration, microsoft-commerce-server

Our main application uses Commerce Server 2002, we are currently in the process of upgrading to 2009.  I am looking into setting up CC.net for both apps.  I have it pulling from SVN and starting the build but it will fail because Commerce Server is not installed so the DLL's are not there.

I don't really want to do a full install of Commerce Server on the CI Server if I can avoid it.  Does anyone have any experience / advice on setting up the CI Server / repo / project so that It would build without CS installed.  currently we do not have any unit tests so that part is not an issue, its getting it to build and being able to do things like FXCop, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no problem in put just the core DLLs of Commerce Server in a "References" directory created under the same structure of your source code.

I have been using this approach in many projects without problems so far.

Maybe, the only problem you'll have now (since you are not using this approach) is that you'll need to refactor a bit your solution to put the references.

Regards,
Alex